# Deploying Laravel on Azure with git from Local Repository producing Error

Tags: php, git, laravel, azure

I am trying to deploy a new Laravel application to an Azure webapp from a local git repository. In the app settings I configured the following as is suggested for deploying laravel on Azure:

App Settings
 - SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH => D:\home\repository
 - SCM_TARGET_PATH => D:\home\site

Virtual Applications and Directories
 - / => site\public

Kudu
 - Composer installed as extension

However when I run *git push repo master* in the command line it runs fine but at the end this is what I see:

```
remote: > php artisan clear-compiled                                                 
remote: .............................................................................
.....................................................................................
...............................                                                      
remote:                                                                              
remote:                                                                              
remote:                                                                              
remote:   [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]                     
remote:                                                                              
remote:   Unable to kill the process                                                 
remote: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeE
xception' with message 'Unable to kill the process' in phar://D:/home/SiteExtensions/
ComposerExtension/Commands/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:779      
remote:                                                                              
remote: Stack trace:                                                                 
remote: #0 phar://D:/home/SiteExtensions/ComposerExtension/Commands/composer.phar/ven
dor/symfony/process/Process.php(173): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->stop()      
remote:                                                                              
remote: #1 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Process\Process->__destruct()      
remote:                                                                              
remote: #2 {main}                                                                    
remote: install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--n
o-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] 
[-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ign
ore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...                                              
remote:   thrown in phar://D:/home/SiteExtensions/ComposerExtension/Commands/composer
.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php on line 779                                 
remote:                                                                              
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.                            
remote:                                                                              
remote:                                                                              
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website fail
ed.                                                                                  
To <url>                                                                           
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

The files are not in D:\home\site but are in the repository. If I use the default settings the files are deployed but I still get the error. However the response time of the site can be extremely slow over 10s sometimes. I am also wondering if this error is to blame. Has anyone deployed laravel on azure recently and had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no necessary to set these App settings to deploy laravel apps to Azure  Web Apps via Git. And by default, the root directory of the web app on Azure is `D:\home\site\wwwroot\`, usually we don’t need to change it.

You can refer to this answer of [Deploy Laravel to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109245/deploy-laravel-to-azure/32111796#32111796) to get steps of deploying laravel  app to Azure. Also if you need to expose public folder to public, you may refer to [laravel 5.1 on windows azure web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708809/laravel-5-1-on-windows-azure-web-application/32715542#32715542).

Especially, according your error message, it seems that you leverage several symfony packages, here is a similar thread on SO ["Unable to kill the process" error with "php composer.phar install" on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672051/unable-to-kill-the-process-error-with-php-composer-phar-install-on-azure/), you can try the methods mentioned there. Otherwise, you can try to first delete cache files, then run the composer command.

Comment: I pushed it without composer, added the extension and then ran the composer install.